# Fabric8 install fails with /var/lib/pgsql/passwd: Permission denied

Tags: postgresql, fabric8

I am just installing Fabric8 into Google Container Engine and each database pod (auth-db, wit-db, init-tenant-db, keycloak-db) fails to start with error:

`/usr/share/container-scripts/postgresql/common.sh: line 127: /var/lib/pgsql/passwd: Permission denied`

I guess it is due to an incompatible change for Fabric8 in PostgreSQL Docker image.

Do you know a workaround?

Comment: Looks like this is not about Kubernetes or GKE. It's very likely that the Fabric8 or Postgres image you're using has broken scripts. You have better chance of following up on this at their GitHub repo than Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You are running into exactly [this](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8/issues/7027)

You can try either:

1. Rebuild the pg 9.6 image using [this](https://github.com/sclorg/postgresql-container/blob/generated/9.6/Dockerfile) and push to your Docker registry and change the k8s StatefulSet/Pod definition
2. Change the StatefulSet/Pod definition in k8s to use the pg 10 image. Perhaps: registry.centos.org/postgresql/postgresql:10
3. Build the pg 10 image using [this](https://github.com/sclorg/postgresql-container/tree/generated/10) and repeat at 1.

Comment: Thank you for research on my issue - I should have done it myself first. I am following the the issue on Github, but no success yet.